# Payment Gateway for Kuwait w/ Subscription Billing Recs

Tags: online-payment

I am building a checkout sequence for a client and am having difficulty finding a payment gateway that will work. Ideally it will need to do the following:

1. Work with clients and credit cards from all GCC countries (Saudi Arabia, UAE, Qatar, Bahrain, and Oman) along with the UK and US.
2. Allow for recurring billing (site offers a month to month subscription and a 3 month subscription
3. Seamlessly integrate into our checkout flow (we don't want to redirect people away from the website to complete their payment.

Options we've explored:

- Stripe and Recurly - neither platform works in Kuwait
- Hesabe - no support for subscriptions (we have to direct bill clients each month)
- Paypal - doesn't seem to work consistently in these countries

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience, I can tell you that there is no such platform that would be optimal in your case while meeting all the required needs and working in all listed countries. If you plan to accept transactions in different foreign currencies, you should establish your “official presence” in each country whose currency you are going to accept. To accomplish this, several banking relationships will need to be established. There are such technologies like UniPay that could meet your needs, but they can only help you get merchant accounts in the UK and US. As to the Emirates, you would need to find a local partner there and apply for merchant accounts to use this technology in that region.